Error processing an error response from a microservice in Spring Reactive API Gateway
I am building a spring app with three microservices: User service, API Gateway and Discovery Service. I am having a problem with the error responses from the user service. For example, when trying to create a user with an email registered previously, the user service returns this response, which is correct:
{
"type": "about:blank",
"title": "Bad Request",
"status": 400,
"instance": "/users",
"errors": \[
"Email already registered"
\]
}

But when I do the request via gateway, this is the response:
An unknown error occurred (with a code 500)

I want to return the response to the client as the user service does without modifications. How to do it? This is the code involved in the gateway:
UserController:
package com.emmariescurrena.bookesy.api_gateway.controllers;

import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.NoFallbackAvailableException;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.ReactiveCircuitBreaker;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationRequiredException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
    private final ReactiveCircuitBreaker circuitBreaker;

    public UserController(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
    ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory) {
        this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
        this.circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("circuit-breaker");
    }

    record CreateUserDto(String auth0UserId, String email, String name, String surname, String bio) {
    }

    record User(Long id,String auth0UserId, String email, String name, String surname, String bio, Date creationDate, String role) {
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserDto userDto) {
        return circuitBreaker.run(
            webClientBuilder.build()
                .post()
                .uri("http://user-service/users")
                .bodyValue(userDto)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, clientResponse ->
                    clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(errorBody -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(errorBody)))
                )
                .toEntity(User.class)
                .map(userResponse -> ResponseEntity.status(userResponse.getStatusCode()).body(userResponse.getBody())),
            throwable -> fallbackMethod(throwable)
        );
    }


    private Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> fallbackMethod(Throwable throwable) {
        log.error("Error occurred: ", throwable);
        if (throwable instanceof ClientAuthorizationRequiredException) {
            return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Authorization required"));
        } else if (throwable instanceof NoFallbackAvailableException) {
            return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).body("Service unavailable"));
        }
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An unknown error occurred"));
    }

}

GlobalExceptionHandler:
 package com.emmariescurrena.bookesy.api_gateway.exceptions;

import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.boot.web.error.ErrorAttributeOptions;
import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.NotFoundException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationRequiredException;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    public GlobalExceptionHandler(
        final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes,
        final WebProperties.Resources resources,
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext,
        final ServerCodecConfigurer configurer
    ) {
        super(errorAttributes, resources, applicationContext);
        setMessageReaders(configurer.getReaders());
        setMessageWriters(configurer.getWriters());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest request) {
        ErrorAttributeOptions options = ErrorAttributeOptions.of(ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.MESSAGE);
        Map<String, Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, options);
        Throwable throwable = getError(request);
        HttpStatusCode httpStatus = determineHttpStatus(throwable);

        if (throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException) {
            WebClientResponseException webClientException = (WebClientResponseException) throwable;
            errorPropertiesMap.put("message", webClientException.getResponseBodyAsString());
            errorPropertiesMap.put("details", webClientException.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } else if (throwable instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            errorPropertiesMap.put("message", "You do not have permission to access this resource.");
        } else {
            errorPropertiesMap.put("message", throwable.getMessage());
        }

        errorPropertiesMap.put("status", httpStatus.value());
        errorPropertiesMap.remove("error");

        return ServerResponse.status(httpStatus)
               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
               .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorPropertiesMap));
    }

    private HttpStatusCode determineHttpStatus(Throwable throwable) {

        if (throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException) {
            return ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getStatusCode();
        } else if (throwable instanceof WebClientRequestException) {
            if (throwable.getCause() instanceof java.net.SocketTimeoutException) {
                return HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT;
            } else if (throwable.getCause() instanceof java.net.UnknownHostException) {
                return HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
            } else if (throwable.getCause() instanceof javax.net.ssl.SSLException) {
                return HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY;
            } else {
                return HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
            }
        } else if (throwable instanceof ResponseStatusException) {
            return ((ResponseStatusException) throwable).getStatusCode();
        } else if (throwable.getCause() instanceof ClientAuthorizationRequiredException) {
            return HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
        } else if (throwable instanceof NotFoundException) {
            return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
        } else if (throwable instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            return HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
        } else {
            // Fallback for unknown exceptions
            log.error("Unknown error occurred: ", throwable); // Log the exception details
            return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;  // Keep the 500 status
        }

    }

}

This is what the console prints:
api-gateway        | 2024-10-17T13:03:42.541Z ERROR 1 --- [api-gateway] [or-http-epoll-5] c.e.b.a.controllers.UserController       : Error reached fallback: 
api-gateway        | 
api-gateway        | java.lang.RuntimeException: {"type":"about:blank","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"instance":"/users","errors":["Email already registered"]}
api-gateway        |    at com.emmariescurrena.bookesy.api_gateway.controllers.UserController.lambda$createUser$0(UserController.java:56) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
api-gateway        |    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
api-gateway        | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ 400 BAD_REQUEST from POST http://user-service/users [DefaultWebClient]
api-gateway        | 2024-10-17T13:03:42.546Z ERROR 1 --- [api-gateway] [or-http-epoll-5] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [7c7ddf50-8]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/users"
api-gateway        | 
api-gateway        | java.lang.RuntimeException: {"type":"about:blank","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"instance":"/users","errors":["Email already registered"]}
api-gateway        |    at com.emmariescurrena.bookesy.api_gateway.controllers.UserController.lambda$createUser$0(UserController.java:56) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
api-gateway        |    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
api-gateway        | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ 400 BAD_REQUEST from POST http://user-service/users [DefaultWebClient]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.emmariescurrena.bookesy.api_gateway.controllers.UserController#createUser(CreateUserDto) [DispatcherHandler]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
api-gateway        |    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/users" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]

I tried different things, like modifying the GlobalExceptionHandler or the fallbackMethod, but I can't make it work and really don't know where to start looking at

The API Gateway has a dedicated route API. You should not have to create a controller and a manual call with a web client. Instead, you should create a route to handle it. For example, you can create a proxy/route based on request path

I was using a bad approach, being that the Discovery Service (eureka server) automatically maps the requests to each service. That means that, except in some specific cases, a controller to manage requests is not needed.
